# How to get a substring of a node in an Xpath expression

Tags: c#, .net, xpath

I'm passing an xpath expression to a XmlDocument and calling SelectNodes(expression) - I'm trying to return just the substring.  So far I've tried

```
substring(//Container/__name,2)
substring(//Container/__name/text(),2)
//Container/__name/substring(.,2)
//Container/__name/text()/substring(.,2)
```

(You can see I'm getting desperate).

They all give errors ("Expression must evaluate to a node set")

//Container/__name/text() works, by the way (and it's 6 characters long).

What's the right way to do this?

EDIT:
Here's the exact code (nothing too spectacular)

```
nodeList = xdoc.SelectNodes(xpathBox.Text);
```

I'm really trying to come up with a pure xpath solution - this is a utility that allows an xml document to be modified by providing an xpath expression and a string - the string is the replacement for the text in the node selected by the xpath expression.  I want to be able to do partial replacements.  So, if what this is not possible, is there any suggestion about how to most elegantly accomplish my goal: replace part of a text node with a string, using only an xpath expression and a string.  Another function perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the result of the evaluation of the XPath is not a node set use `Evaluate` instead than `SelectNodes`:

```
  string substr = xdoc.CreateNavigator().Evaluate("substring(//Container/__name,2)") as string;
```

To modify the text inside all the `__name` elements you can do something like this:

```
  foreach (XmlNode node in xdoc.SelectNodes("//Container/__name")) {
    XmlElement nameElement = node as XmlElement;
    nameElement.InnerText = nameElement.InnerText.Substring(2);
  }
```

Comment: I've been slowly figuring out how to use Evaluate(), but it seems like a) that doesn't quite accomplish what I'm trying to do and b) maybe it's not possible to do what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I see - if you have a specific problem with Evaluate() post it, I use it quite a lot...if it is not possible to do what you are trying to do, well, sorry!

Comment: Thanks MiMo, it was an observation (maybe with an implied question), not a complaint.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that where you're trying to execute this. The return value is being expected as a node set, and you're trying to return a string.

You need to return the node first, and then just perform a string function on it.

Once you return the `text()` node to your code, where you can check that it's 6 characters long, can you run substring on that?

`var new = old.Substring(1,2)`